# Multiple errors importing huge CSV. How to diagnose?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv with over 1 million rows that I'm trying to import. Unfortunately I can't share a sample of the data but this is the code I'm using to import it:

```
transactions = pd.read_csv('bank_raw_data.csv',
                           sep=',',
                           error_bad_lines=False,
                           warn_bad_lines=True,
                           engine='python',
                           encoding='ISO-8859-1',
                           escapechar='\\',
                           skiprows=[i for i in range(1,263)])
```

I skip rows that have errors, and below is a section of errors I'm getting:

```
Skipping line 1294103: ',' expected after '"'
Skipping line 1300423: field larger than field limit (131072)
Skipping line 1300695: NULL byte detected. This byte cannot be processed in Python's native csv library at the moment, so please pass in engine='c' instead
Skipping line 1294273: Expected 21 fields in line 1294273, saw 31
```

Unfortunately I can't check the csv in Excel due to it's size so I don't know whats' going on in line 12455 etc.

Any advice on how to diagnose these errors?

I have also changed encoding to `encoding='cp1252'` but get the error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 4082: character maps to <undefined>`

The reason I tried `cp1252` as the encoding is this:

```
with open('bank_raw_data.csv') as f:
    print(f)

<_io.TextIOWrapper name='bank_raw_data.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

But it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the specific line through:

`Powershell`

```
Get-Content filename.csv | Select -Index x-1
```

Note Select starts on 0, so to read line 10 you'd write `-Index 9`

`Bash`

```
cat filename.csv | awk 'NR==x'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are number of tools that can help you validate csv files, including:

https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine

https://github.com/Clever/csvlint